# Why can't magento accept `content` as a database field name?

Tags: forms, magento, customization

I am creating a new module and in that module I add a form which has a field name `content` in the database.

Now when I add a wyswig editor in this form with the field name `content` in the database, the layout of the form in the backend changes completely as compared to default layout.

But when I changed the database field name from `content` to any other name lets say `content_html` or `content_h` etc etc., the layout of the form now appeared as a default form.

This happens only when I use wyswig editor, and without wyswig if I create simple form it accepts the values in the database under the `content` field name.

Why can't magento accept the `content` as a field name, using wyswig editor.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that magento sets the `id` of the element to same as the `name` and the `id`
`content` is already present:

```
<div class="main-col" id="content">
```

try to set a prefix to your for your form

```
$form->setHtmlIdPrefix('something_')
```

that should fix it

Comment: but it is happen only while using wyswyg editor, other than that it accept the `content` as a database field name.

Comment: like i said, when you create the field with the name "content" magento will also use it as the "id" of the field so you will get something like "<textare name="content" id="content">". the problem is that 'id="contetn"' already exists and so the wysiwyg editor will be rendered in the wrong place. to prevent this you can set a prefix for all element ids in the form with "$form->setHtmlIdPrefix('something_')" which should solve your issues